Safari does not apply CSS animation on SVG elements that are referenced via `<use>`
I'm trying to animate an element in SVG that is inserted via the <use> element. This works on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari.
Here is a proof of concept:


<svg
  viewBox="0 0 200 100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
  style="width: 100%"
>
  <defs>
    <circle id="t" class="test" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="hotpink"/>
  </defs>

  <!-- This circle is *not* animated -->
  <use href="#t"></use>

  <!-- This circle is animated -->
  <circle class="test" cx="110" cy="50" r="25" fill="hotpink"/>

  <style>
    .test {
      animation: 3s test infinite;
      /*
        proof that the styles are applied: both
        circles are limegreen rather than hot pink
      */
      fill: limegreen;
    }

    @keyframes test {
      from {
        translate: 0 0;
      }
      to {
        translate: 0 -10px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</svg>



In Firefox and Chrome, both circles will properly bounce up and down. On Safari, only the left circle is animated.
I already tried to move the @keyframes inside the <defs> block and even inside a wrapping <g>, but nothing helped so far. To me it looks like this is a bug in Safari, but how can I circumvent it?

maybe try rewriting in SMIL.

Apparently a known issue. See webkit bug report #173154.

@RobertLongson I guess it would work, but I have to use CSS variables for what I want to do. I don't think I can use CSS variables inside <animate> attributes, right?

@herrstrietzel Thanks for the link! What a bummer. I guess then my implementation will be "progressive enhancement"

You can still Animate the use el itself by adding the class

@herrstrietzel I'm using nested <use>. The outer <use> for a row of cubes and the inner <use> for each cube in the row. But knowing that this doesn't work in Safari, I will most likely refactor it the way you proposed. That will make the SVG much larger, but at least there is a workaround.
